# In Python3, for Unix, we have os.sync(). What is its counterpart for windows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I am trying to handle writing, getting(through SFTP) and file management of large amount files. I see that after writing a file, I am checking for the file with os.path.exits for the file which is resulting in False. After some time around (10-15 secs), I am able to see the files present there. I am checking for the data to be flushed and the memory to be refreshed. I was able to os.sync() which looks like suits my problem. But its for Unix, what is its counterpart for Windows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `f.flush()` and `os.fsync()`:

```
with open(...) as f:
    ...
    f.flush()
    os.fsync(f.fileno())
```

Comment: Thank you, that will help. I will try that. Any similar thing for the SFTP files. Around 90% which are in the situation are them.